# Books (or other references) for extracting XML data with R

Tags: xml, r

I'll give a course on how to extract data from XML/HTML using R. I do have some practical experience doing this (most of it I learnt by myself, using help from SO), but I'd like some reference to help me organize my thoughts and the course.

Does anyone know any reference (can be a book, lectures notes, websites etc.) on extracting XML/HTML data using R?

Untill now I only found [this short introduction](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/Tour.pdf) to the XML package.

ps.: I know this is not exactly a programming question, but it's related and I've seen related questions here before.

Comment: IMO, that reference is sufficient to teach you everything you need to know about using R with XML.  Everything else is xpath.  So the bulk of the learning is actually about xpath, and there are many resources for that.

Comment: I'll look for references for xpath. Thanks.

Comment: The [xpath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) is actually quite readable and informative, especially [section 2.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) for a quick introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book has a subsection on XML processing (Section 8.5 XML; p. 254-264)

> Gentleman, R., 2009. R Programming for Bioinformatics, Boca Raton: CRC
>   Press.